# How can I get Mac Voiceover to read numbers as numbers instead of individual digits?

Tags: macos, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

When I render a number in a span tag, Mac Voiceover is reading individual digits instead of numbers. For example, 10 is read as "one zero" instead of "ten".

How can I make it read "ten" instead of "one zero"?

I have searched for answers, but it seems most people have the opposite problem. CSS properties like speak and speak-as seem to have no effect.

If you'd like to see an example, try loading up the following pen and having Mac Voiceover read it (to use Mac Voiceover, use Command + f5).

https://codepen.io/davescode/full/GeGLYv

Or literally just: `<span>10</span>`

Comment: Does voiceover read numbers in other applications or does it **always** read digits even outside of browser applications?

Comment: I would also suggest you file a bug about the non-supported CSS attributes by macOS VoiceOver at bugreport.apple.com. My understanding is that having such bugs filed by external developers is appreciated by Apple's accessibility team as it helps prioritize future work.

Comment: @zero298 I was also experiencing this outside of the browser. Your solution resolved both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that your VoiceOver settings are set to read numbers as words:

[image: Numbers as words]

Whenever I access the codepen from your question using these settings in Safari, the number is read as the word "ten", instead of the digits, "one zero".